# Black and white movie about a fog that kills a seaside town

Tags: story-identification, movie

My Mom swears she saw a movie on TV in the 1970s where a fog rolls into a town by the ocean and people start disappearing.

She remembers there being a lighthouse, and the fog looked like normal, dense fog.

She says it isn't *The Fog* (1980) and it might have been based off a book.

Comment: I think I was thinking of [*The Crawling Eye*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052320/), but it doesn't have the vanishings I remember.

Comment: She insisted The Fog was based off of it, and looks like The Crawling Eye inspired it a bit. I think she got the two movies confused.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that your mother may be thinking of [*The Crawling Eye*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0052320/), from 1958, aka [*The Trollenberg Terror*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Trollenberg_Terror).

> On the Swiss mountain Trollenberg, one of three student climbers is suddenly killed, his head ripped from his body. Two sisters, Anne and Sarah Pilgrim, a London mind-reading act, are travelling by train to Geneva when Anne faints as the train passes the mountain. Upon waking, Anne insists that they must get off at the next stop.
>
> UN troubleshooter Alan Brooks, in the same train compartment as the sisters, is going to Trollenberg's observatory to meet with Professor Crevett. Crevett goes on to explain that, despite many climbing accidents, no bodies are ever found, and an always-stationary radioactive cloud is regularly observed on the mountain's south face. Brooks mentions similar incidents that took place in the Andes three years earlier, just before a similar radioactive cloud vanished without a trace. Local rumors circulated that something was living in the heavy mist.

### Trailer